# (Data Structure) Java LinkedList objects to Tree

Tags: java, jsp, recursion, tree, linked-list

I have a class A like this:

```
class A {
    Long id;
    String name;
    Long parentId; // refers to another A object's id
}
```

Now I get the list of A objects, and I want to put them all to a data-structure like "folder tree" in PC, and then view that tree on GUI using JSP but I do not know how to implement this. So could you please help on these 2 problems:
 1. How to build a "folder tree" from a given list of objects? Is there any available API support this?
 2. How can we browse that whole data tree and view it on JSP as folder tree  without using recursion? (I mean what is the best way to display them)
Thank you so much.

Comment: You have two attributes: `Long id` and `Long parentId` to associate every node to it's parent. What have you tried to solve this? If you don't have any idea, please take a pencil and a paper and think on something (because this looks like a homework exercise).

Comment: So you mean object of `A` contains reference(s) to other `A` objects?

Comment: @NishantShreshth: Yes, it contains its parent's id, not parent object

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: There are so much stuff behind related this problem but I am trying to simplify it on above question; and now I am stuck on finding what kind of data-structure to keep my data and the way to show it on GUI (using JSP)

Comment: If that's your real question, then you can just have (based on your design) a `List<A> childrenNodes` as attribute of `A` class. If you can't do this modification, create a wrapper class that contains `A node; List<A> childrenNodes`.

Comment: instead of referring to another object's id, why don't you refer directly to the object? So... `Long id; String name; A parent;` and then `List<A> children;`

Comment: @vikingsteve maybe the data comes in format proposed by OP. What you propose would be the design of the solution (and this would be a `A'` class).

Comment: This project does not use any ORM for mapping parent-child from DB to object. All model objects are plain objects. Assume that I can create a transient list of childs in A, so how can I attach them (the childs )to their parent? And do the same thing for remain childs at lower levels?

Comment: Why don't you first build a list of the raw-data coming from the DB and then create a tree from the data, where a node does not store the id but a reference to the real parent object?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I assume that you can change your `A` class to look like this:

```
class A {
    Long id;
    String name;
    Long parentId; // refers to another A object's id
    List<A> childrenNodes = new ArrayList();
}
```

Now, assuming you have a `List<A> lstData` filled with all the data and you want to convert it into a Tree, you can use the following code/algorithm:

```
public List<A> convertIntoTree(List<A> lstData) {
    for(A parentA : lstData) {
        //setting the children nodes for parentA
        for(A childA : lstData) {
            if (childA.getParentId() == parentA.getId()) {
                parentA.getChildrenNodes().add(childA);
            }
        }
    }
    //the main tree
    List<A> lstParents = new ArrayList<A>();
    //filling the tree
    for(A parentA : lstData) {
        //change this for your check if parent function or another rule
        if (parentA.getParentId() == 0) {
            lstParents.add(parentA);
        }
    }
    return lstParents;
}
```